Phemex API Error When Placing Orders Through CCXT in a Discord Bot (Leveraged Trading
I'm developing a trading bot integrated with Discord, using the CCXT library to handle orders on Phemex. Despite following the documentation closely and trying both market and limit orders, I consistently receive an error which doesn't have a clear description in the Phemex docs or CCXT's issues. Here's an example command for the Discord bot:
/start symbol:FETUSDT leverage:3 size:15 line_value:2.43
Here's the error:
error: Critical: Error executing sell limit order for FETUSDT: phemex {"code":39999,"msg":"Error in place order","data":null} {"timestamp":"2024-04-20T18:31:52.978Z"}

Here is the key part of the code involved in placing orders:
const executeBuyOrder = async (symbol, size, price, leverage, posSide = 'long') => {
  try {
    logger.info(`Executing limit buy order for ${symbol}, size: ${size}, price: ${price}, leverage: ${leverage}, posSide: ${posSide}`);
    const market = await phemex.loadMarkets();
    const marketSymbol = market[symbol].id;
    const params = {
      'leverage': leverage,
      'posSide': posSide // Include posSide in the parameters
    };
    const response = await phemex.createLimitBuyOrder(marketSymbol, size, price, params);
    logger.info('Limit buy order executed:', response);
    return response;
  } catch (error) {
    logger.error('Failed to execute limit buy order:', error.message, error.stack);
    throw error; // Rethrow the error to handle it in the calling function
  }
};

const executeSellOrder = async (symbol, size, price, leverage, posSide = 'short') => {
  try {
    logger.info(`Executing limit sell order for ${symbol}, size: ${size}, price: ${price}, leverage: ${leverage}, posSide: ${posSide}`);
    const market = await phemex.loadMarkets();
    const marketSymbol = market[symbol].id;
    const params = {
      'leverage': leverage,
      'posSide': posSide // Include posSide in the parameters
    };
    const response = await phemex.createLimitSellOrder(marketSymbol, size, price, params);
    logger.info('Limit sell order executed:', response);
    return response;
  } catch (error) {
    logger.error('Failed to execute limit sell order:', error.message, error.stack);
    throw error; // Rethrow the error to handle it in the calling function
  }
};

And the function definition to send order requests:
// Function to construct and send order requests to the Phemex API
async function placeOrder(orderDetails) {
  const { symbol, type, side, amount, price, params } = orderDetails;
  const exchange = new ccxt.phemex({
    apiKey: process.env.PHEMEX_API_KEY, 
    secret: process.env.PHEMEX_SECRET, 
  });

  try {
    let order;
    switch (type) {
      case 'limit':
        order = await exchange.createLimitOrder(symbol, side, amount, price, params);
        break;
      case 'market':
        order = await exchange.createMarketOrder(symbol, side, amount, params);
        break;
      case 'stop':
      case 'stopLimit':
      case 'marketIfTouched':
      case 'limitIfTouched':
        // Additional handling for advanced order types
        order = await exchange.createOrder(symbol, type, side, amount, price, params);
        break;
      default:
        throw new Error(`Unsupported order type: ${type}`);
    }
    logger.info(`Order placed successfully: ${JSON.stringify(order)}`);
    return order;
  } catch (error) {
    logger.error(`Failed to place order for ${symbol} - ${type} - ${side}: ${error.message}`, error.stack);
    throw error; // Rethrow the error after logging
  }
}


Questions:

What does error code 39999 typically signify on Phemex when placing orders via CCXT?

Are there specific parameters or setup steps I might be missing that could lead to this error?

Maybe I have it in the wrong order?

Has anyone experienced similar issues with Phemex on CCXT and found a workaround?


I've already tried toggling between market and limit orders and experimented with different parameters without any success. Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!
